# Android system code via SMSManager

Tags: android, smsmanager

I have some question about Android System codes like this one - `*#*#4636#*#*`.
So my question is about, is it possible to send those codes via SMS? If yes, how I can do it? and will the phone executes those codes when it was received?

Comment: You can send your code just like you would any other text message, but the recipient's device isn't going to treat it any differently than any other message. Your app would need to receive and handle the incoming message, and execute it itself.

Comment: @MikeM. so only client-server app and no other issues?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.